# Update all versions in maven

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3

I've got a maven project with a large number of sub-projects with many dependencies. Now I'd like to update all versions of my pom files to a new version and rebuild them. For example if I've got a a pom like that:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>theparentId</groupId>
    <artifactId>theParentArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>eaics-wsa-model</artifactId>
<packaging>model</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId1</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId1</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId2</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId3</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId3</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I need to update the dependencies of groupId1 to groupId3 to a new version which doesn't exist jet. Because I also need to "create" a new updated version of my dependencies themself.

Because the dependencies in their pom.xml look like that at the moment:

```
<groupId>groupId3</groupId>
<artifactId>artifactId3</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
```

As you see, the version is on 1.2 but needs to be updated to 1.3 before the dependency uses it.

So is there a way to recursively update all pom (versions)? If it's possible in Java with MavenXpp3Reader etc. great. But is there a more simple method? Because my fear is, that I can't build my projects after that, because I think they don't build recursively and won't find the new dependency versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can update all the pom's version using [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/set.html) There a some examples that can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But will they build recursive? I've a lot of project-dependencies and So i need to update these versions first, build them in the maven local repository and change the version of the dependency after.

Comment: It is recursive if all the module keep the same version. For your specific scenario check this example http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/set.html you can set for each project. You can use your own script to manage this process settings first all the dependencies and then update parent project setting properties

Answer (score 0):

Updated Link: https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/index.html
And the command to update all versions is `mvn versions:use-latest-versions`